# Multi touch in desktop browser (Like Google Maps in IE9)

Tags: javascript, maps, multi-touch

I'm trying to create a multi touch web application, but I cannot get any desktop browser to receive multi touch events - only "click events". (It works on my iPhone where).

The only working example of a multi touch web application I've seen is Google Maps in IE9 on Windows 7 where you can pinch to zoom using two fingers. (It doesn't work in Chrome or FireFox).

Does anyone know how to create multi touch enabled websites for desktop browsers?

Br,

Comment: In bing maps pinch to zoom works also, though I wonder how they do it, since IE9 has no multi touch apis(only IE10 has).